# How to fix 'fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported' - graceful-fs

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Recently I've made a switch to Node v.6, and It started creating more and more problems with running normal builds grunt/gulp/webpack

For example:

```
$ gulp
[14:02:20] Local gulp not found in ~/_Other/angular-2-ts/angular2-seed
[14:02:20] Try running: npm install gulp
```

while gulp and all other plugins and modules are installed (and even re-installed via `rm -rf node_modules`) in /node_modules folder.

Most of those errors have line like

```
(node:42) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. 
If you are using the graceful-fs module, 
please update it to a more recent version.
```

with 42 as arbitrary number

Like in that issue I've submitted - in angular2-seed repo https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/902

What I've tried to do is downgrade to Node v.5 via n (https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) - it worked. Then remove all `node_modules` folders, then do

```
npm info graceful-fs -v
3.3.6
```

ok, lets upgrade or remove and install new:

```
npm i graceful-fs@latest
npm i graceful-fs@4.1.4
sudo npm i graceful-fs@4.1.4 -g
```

all results in

```
npm info graceful-fs -v
3.3.6
```

So now I am currenlty stuck with **graceful-fs 3.3.6** or even worse in some modules dependances, like

```
$ angular2-seed
$ npm install

//other lines..
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before 
will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 
as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

What could be the strategy here:

- Manually patch all the deps that contain graceful-fs < 4.0.0?
- There's some global switch to use specific package version?
- Reinstall everything?

Comment: I am having same issue with Gulp and some of my modules. I fixed my modules by upgrading the modules to use the latest graceful-fs, but I am not sure there is a solution to fix other modules that have not upgraded yet.

Comment: Looks like this won't be fixed in Gulp 3.x and you will have to upgrade to Gulp 4.x https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1571

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I had this problem and I was able to fix this by updating `npm`

```
sudo npm update -g npm
```

Before the update, the result of `npm info graceful-fs | grep 'version:'` was:

```
version: '3.3.12'
```

After the update the result is:

```
version: '3.9.3'
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorge. This helped fix the problem. I am still getting appname@0.1.x /path/of/app with graceful-fs@4.1.4 highlighted every time I run npm install in my app directory. but I am living with that for now.

Comment: Hi @Geo, same here, look at the answer by analog-nico, we have different versions of the same package because other tools depend strictly on those versions. To get rid of the warning we need to upgrade all of them or look for replacements.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to run `nvm use v6.2.1`

Comment: Please note that `npm info graceful-fs -v` returns the version of npm (it is the same as running `npm -v`) and NOT graceful-fs. To get graceful-fs version, use something like `npm info graceful-fs | grep version:`.

Comment: @Asimov This worked for me too. Also, if you reinstalled NodeJS recently (I installed Node through the package on their website and then replaced it with the one from homebrew) run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` in the project home folder.

Comment: @nstCactus do you know where that's looking? Running your command gives me **4.1.6**, but running the command from analog-nico ([below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37470253/1241736)) shows me **4.1.4** in gulp-util@3.0.7, and **1.2.3 and 3.0.8** in vinyl-fs (fwiw this is node 6.3.1 via nvm)

Answer (score 73):

Type `npm list graceful-fs` and you will see which versions of graceful-fs are currently installed.

In my case I got:

```
npm list graceful-fs

@request/promise-core@0.0.1 /projects/request/promise-core
+-- gulp@3.9.1
| `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14
|   +-- glob-watcher@0.0.6
|   | `-- gaze@0.5.2
|   |   `-- globule@0.1.0
|   |     `-- glob@3.1.21
|   |       `-- graceful-fs@1.2.3        <==== !!!
|   `-- graceful-fs@3.0.8 
`-- publish-please@2.1.3
  +-- nsp@2.4.0
  | `-- nodesecurity-npm-utils@4.0.1
  |   `-- silent-npm-registry-client@2.0.0
  |     `-- npm-registry-client@7.1.0
  |       `-- graceful-fs@4.1.3 
  `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
    `-- load-json-file@1.1.0
      `-- graceful-fs@4.1.4
```

As you can see `gulp` deep down depends on a very old version. Unfortunately, I can't update that myself using `npm update graceful-fs`. `gulp` would need to update their dependencies. So if you have a case like this you are out of luck. But you may open an issue for the project with the old dependency - i.e. `gulp`.

Comment: FYI, in your specific example, `gulp` won't change it in version 3 but only in version 4: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1571

Comment: this was it for me, final push to remove gulp

Comment: In my case, the pre-v4 `graceful-fs` module dependency was coming from `npm` itself (version 3.10.3) via `cmd-shim@2.0.2`.  I didn't see this until I listed the _global_ `graceful-fs` dependencies using `npm list -g graceful-fs`.

Comment: This helped me solve it. My graceful-fs package was up-to-date, but a few other packages still relied on an older version.

Answer (score 21):

Solved this bug with reinstall gulp

```
npm uninstall gulp
npm install gulp
```

Comment: Sounds like gulp have fixed this issue - couldn't remember if I installed gulp with --save-dev or not before but your way worked from my project folder.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me too

Comment: Yeah, looks like an older Gulp dependency problem.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting node_modules folder contents and running

```
npm install bower
npm install
```

solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406482/1587329), you can also attempt the command

```
npm cache clean
```

That fixed it for me, after the other steps had not fully yielded results (other than updating everything).

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out that cordova brings in it's own npm with the graceful-fs dependency, so if you use Cordova make sure that it is the latest so you get the latest graceful-fs from that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by:

1. updating by `package.json`
2. deleting the node_modules folder
3. executing `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

if you are running nvm you might want to run `nvm use <desired-node-version>` This keeps node consistent with npm

Answer (score 0):

Or try to update `node`:

```
brew upgrade node
```

If it is installed with `brew` (like in my case). `sudo npm update -g npm` did not solve the "same" problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The report says : a file is missing in ... vendor/win32-x64-48/binding.node

I looked for the binding.node file and I find it in...

https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries

Copy the correct file with the name binding.node and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of my Cordova-project, uninstalling and installing cordova -g fixed the problem for me.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```