# Ionic2 throws error while running `ionic serve` fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, gulp

The solution defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346512/how-to-fix-fs-re-evaluating-native-module-sources-is-not-supported-graceful) is not helping me in anyways.

I am getting this error:

```
(node:15085) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
```

My system info:

`OS X EL Capitan v 10.11.5` and using `node v6.3.1 (npm v3.10.6)`

```
sh$ gulp -v
    CLI version 1.2.2
    Local version 3.9.1
```

Comment: Does it still produce the app or does it abort at that message? I am getting the same error but never really had any problems stemming from it.

Comment: @TinoA. App is produced successfully but only the message is bothering me.

Comment: Well if you are not using the graceful-fs module then this shoul not concern you