# Cannot find module 'internal/fs' after upgrading to node 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs, bower

We've recently tried to upgrade to node v7.0.0 on our build server, but started to have issues during the application build task failing on the ["bower_concat" step](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat):

```
Loading "bower-concat.js" tasks...ERROR
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
```

What we have installed:

- `node` v7.0.0 (installed via `yum` ["nodesource" repository](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora))
- `npm` 4.0.1
- using `grunt` (if this is relevant)
- `grunt-bower-concat` 0.6.0

The grunt build task configuration:

```
grunt.registerTask(
    'build:prod', [
        'clean:prod',
        'copy:prod',
        'replace',
        'bower_concat',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'injector:prod',
        'copy:cssfix',
        'copy:dist',
        'bowercopy:dist',
        'bowercopy:fonts',
        'template:setProdVersion'
    ]
);
```

And the grunt `bower_concat` task:

```
bower_concat: {
    all: {
        dest: '<%= app.build %>/bower.js',
        cssDest: '<%= app.build %>/bower.css',
        dependencies: {
            'bootstrap': 'jquery'
        },
        mainFiles: {
            "angular-app-modules": [
                "app/dist/angular-app-modules.min.js",
                "app/dist/angular-app-modules.min.css"
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Note that it works without any problems on node v6.9.0.

What can be causing the issue? Can we workaround the problem without downgrading to node v6?

---

There is also [this relevant issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14438), but, as of now, the information there does not help in our case.

Comment: It sounds like the previous version was not properly replaced or permissions are screwy, but this isn't nearly enough info to tell. I've seen this before (while running our build cluster) with other modules, but it was always a partially bad install and I usually just respin the box.

Comment: @ssube thanks, yeah, I tend to think this is a bad install as well (not sure, how to reliably verify it though).  When I was google-searching this, I've seen people reinstalling node helped when a similar error was thrown. I've tried that numerous times, but, I guess, I need to start with a completely fresh box. Also, [some people reported](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14438#issuecomment-256752070) that installing npm 4 alongside with node 7 helped to solve the problem..but I have npm 4 installed. Okay, I'll see if having a fresh box will help.

Comment: Try cd'ing into `node_modules/bower-concat` and then run `npm install` from there. Then try running your build task again from proj root. Any improvement?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First, open the console as administrator (or in the terminal with `sudo` if it is a Linux) and:

```
npm cache clean
```

For npm 5 and later

```
npm cache clean --force
```

---

**Edit:**

For windows you might fail to clean the cache, so you can remove the cache manually by deleting all the following folder content:

```
C:\Users\<USER-NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Thanks "superwf", this case might happen for some, but I never had to do this (maybe because of my lowest security level?!).

**End Edit.**

---

Then go back to the normal console (not administrator or root), return to your project directory where the package.json is located, and then delete the `node_modules` folder from your project, remove it completely, and then install node modules again inside your project folder:

```
npm install
```

You might need to update your modules before installing modules again. I recommend this, but **be careful of breaking changes** if there are any major version changes in your modules.
This module [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates) can help you to check the latest version and update them.

Also, you maybe need to install the latest global modules as well, check updates by:

```
ncu -g
```

or

```
npm outdated -g
```

If you're still stuck, you might need to remove the global `node_modules` folder and reinstall what you want again.

---

**Edit**:

**Yarn option**: Some people ended with the same issues even with the cleanup procedures, actually you save your time a lot using [**Yarn**](https://yarnpkg.com).
Personally, I started to use `yarn` instead of traditional `npm i`, I can guarantee it is faster, and save your time, and your head from npm headaches.

Comment: On windows, after installing node 8.x npm install was reporting running version 3.x and I had to delete the folder C:\Users\<USER-NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm and reinstall node 8.x to get it to upgrade to NPM version 5.x

Comment: @SimonHutchison just for a recommendation, for now, npm 5 is not really stable yet for me, causing many issues, I downgraded because of node-sass, as many said it is an issue to do with npm.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I agree, but I regardless of the version, npm was in a bad state and not working at all.The comment by superwf below recommending deleting both the `C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm` and `npm-cache` folders, worked for me.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me - in addition to the folders in the user profile, I also had to delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules` and then repair the installation from the MSI.

Comment: The location listed is incorrect. I found mine under `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\npm-cache`

Answer (score 19):

In my case clearing the cache (OSX) did not work. I use `n` to manage node which causes `npm` to potentially be out of date. According to [n docs](https://github.com/tj/n) you can update `npm` with:

```
curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Comment: After running this I get: No such file or directory for npm command... which is fine if it's only a path issue but it would be good to note. (Upvoted)

Comment: It will work without `sudo` though: `curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh`, especially if you manually deleted the folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 14):

In linux，when I update to node 7, this happened, "npm cache clean" does work.

In windows, npm cache clean also generate

> Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'

Just remove

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

solved

Answer (score 11):

In my case clearing the cache did not work. Below was my initial state and how I resolved this:

```html
node -v v7.4.0
npm -v 4.0.5
```

I resolved by doing the following and using n manager:

```html
$ sudo n 6.9.1
$ sudo npm -g install npm@next
$ sudo n stable
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why installing with `sudo`? it sounds like you have permissions messed up at first place, I suggest looking into this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 6):

I use the [n tool](https://github.com/tj/n) to manage switching between node (and the bundled npm) versions.

To fix this error, I simply removed npm from the global space (macOS): `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`

I then re-ran sudo n latest. This will re-install npm. When switching back to previous version of node just run sudo n 4.3.2.

To summarise:

```
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
> sudo n latest
> node --version
v7.7.1
> npm --version
4.1.2
> sudo n 4.3.2
> npm --version
2.14.12
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was to

> 1) Delete node_modules/

```
sudo rm -R node_modules/
```

> 2) Re-run gulp

`gulp`

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Windows 8.1 x64 , upgrading from v6 to v7.
I got this issue on global installation
I have many packages installed already, but every time I ran npm command, whether `npm install, npm list,npm update` etc. always return the same error

This step works for me:

1. Clean npm cache **manually** by deleting npm-cache folder located at

> C:\Users[usrname]\AppData\Roaming\

2. **Remove/rename  npm** folder in my NodeJS installation directory. In this case , **I rename npm folder to npm--** in

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules

3. Re-install NodeJS v7

Everything works fine then

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the last version of bower

```
> npm install -g bower
```

Apparently, npm > 4.0 do not use internal/fs module.

Comment: what have bower to do with this issue?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is not directly related. The problem is with grunt-bower-concat, it uses an older version of bower. Here is a related comment on similar issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14438#issuecomment-257113705

Comment: Yes, you are right Anis. this is the problem related to bower version.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case clearing the cache did not work. What did work was deleting the `node_modules/npm` folder within my nodejs install location. Then running the nodejs installer again and using the 'repair' option (note: this is for Windows).

From what I could gather in the npm debug log, it looked like my old version of npm wasn't completely removed before the new version was installed. So there were some lingering deprecated modules in the folder where npm was installed.

Answer (score 2):

If using mac

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions
```

and remove node folder

Answer (score 2):

I solve this by installing NVM to manage Node

https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

after install NVM, reinstall node

```
nvm install node
```

Answer (score 1):

On Win10 this worked for me: (adjust to relevant node version and username)

- Uninstall node (via node-v7.8.0-x64.msi)
- Remove the folders 'npm' and 'npm-cache' in 'C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming
- Install node again (via node-v7.8.0-x64.msi)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue after a Node v4.X to v7.8.0 upgrade.  Reinstalling NPM and a latest check, got me to a working NPM v4.5.0.

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me.

In the end I reinstalled node and ionic and that did the trick:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g

npm uninstall node
npm install node -g
```

My system information before fixing the issue:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11         <-- way too old
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.4
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v8.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `n` to update `node` versions and all npm commands are failing with this message that means you have latest node but an older npm version.

so in this case do the following, (may need sudo)

`n 4.7
npm install npm -g
n latest`

it will go back to node 4.7 and then install latest npm using it. after than it will come back to latest npm version. (replace latest with whatever version you actually want)

Answer (score 0):

1) sudo npm cache clean -f

2) sudo npm install -g n

3) sudo n stable

Just Three Steps :)

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Again npm install. It will Works