# After node reinstalled: "Cannot find module 'internal/util/types' "

Tags: node.js, npm

So I had removed node from my computer (mostly, I thought) a couple months ago, and today I reinstalled it. Node's working okay, but when I try to test npm I get this message:

```
$ npm
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

I tried using "npm rebuild" as I've seen suggested, but that has no impact on anything. I'm using Node v8.11.2 on Windows (hell if I know what version of NPM). Any clues?

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308623/cannot-find-module-internal-fs-after-upgrading-to-node-7/40406482#40406482

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In windows,

- Step 1: Go to **`\global_modules\node_modules,`** 
  (C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm )
  (C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)
- Step 2: Delete the **`"npm"`** folder and all its contents,
- Step 3: Go to **`https://nodejs.org`**,
- Step 4: Download the "Recommended For Most Users" version),
- Step 5: Install it

Comment: "/global_modules/"... where is this?

Comment: C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: I do not see global_modules in  either of those folders

Comment: I had similar issues, i had to delete the AppData\Roaming\npm and AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folders.  Then after re-installing node, I can do the npm command without that error.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked.

delete package-lock.json

```
npm i graceful-fs
npm i vinyl-fs
```

Comment: After trying several things I think that fix was delete package-lock.json -thx

Answer (score 2):

From your terminal, run

```
rm -rf ./node_modules

npm update

npm install npm@latest -g
```

or

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

These should help fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. Solved it by going to %AppData% and deleting npm and npm-cache folders.