# Cannot find module 'internal/fs' not working as per the existing solutions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I'm getting the following issue all the time while going to run my project. Even after downgraded my node version to 8.4.0 (npm version 5.3.0) still getting the same issue. I know there are so many solutions given like after removing the `node_modules` to run `npm cache clean --force` and then again `npm install` but this solution is not working as well.

PFB, the error:

```
npm start

m> subhojits-components@0.0.1 start 
/home/subhojit/Desktop/my_project
> node server/index

Unspecified environment, booting dev server
Booting dev server....
module.js:491
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:40:20
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/subhojit/Desktop/my_project/node_modules/express- 
handlebars/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! subhojits-components@0.0.1 start: `node server/index`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the subhojits-components@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

Please let me know if there are anymore solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm using graceful-fs version 4.0.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module 'internal/fs' after upgrading to node 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308623/cannot-find-module-internal-fs-after-upgrading-to-node-7)

Comment: that i also know its a possible duplicate of that question but I tried with that solution as well but its not working

Answer (score 0):

hi please import the graceful-fs library

like

```
import {userDefinedName} from 'graceful-fs';
```

hope it will help you.

or Click On the below Link.

[graceful-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs)

Comment: This solution is not helping @Divakar

Comment: did you go through the that link @Subhojit

Comment: can you send your code, which you are using 'graceful-fs'

Comment: that's not possible

Comment: its okay, which version node you're using @Subhojit

Comment: give me some time i'll get back to you...@Subhojit

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error on external Apple engine.

[Uninstalling the currently active version of node.js with nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240567/uninstalling-the-currently-active-version-of-node-js-with-nvm)

**So uninstall npm:**

```
nvm deactivate
nvm uninstall <<version>>
```

**Install stable version**

```
nvm install <<version>>
nvm install 10.15.3
```

**Install Angular/Cli (exemple)**

```
npm install @angular/cli
npm link @angular/cli
```

*Wish, it works.*

Comment: Thank you @Gromph. But this solution didn't work and I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** not Apple engine.