# error on adding platform, graceful-fs module

Tags: node.js, ionic2, ionic-cli

i started a new ionic project on adding android platform i get this error

> FS:re-evaluvating native module source is not supported. if you are using graceful-fs module .please update it

[image: my grace full versions]

[image: error in my terminal window]

its a new ionic 2 project could some one help me.

i tried everything in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346512/how-to-fix-fs-re-evaluating-native-module-sources-is-not-supported-graceful)

Answer (score 0):

The fs module error is not actually stopping your command from running. The first error you hit is actually the one that says:

```
ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" is not in your PATH. You must fulfil at least one of these conditions.
```

Have you installed the Android SDK tools on your system? I'd recommend going through the setup process [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) if not before continuing.